# Issue runnuing Unit Test Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to Run a simple Unit Test but the Test Explorer shows that there is no run test
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRiIL.png

Digging in the test output, I am getting the following error:

```
'executor://mstestadapter/v2' : Could not find file 'C:\Users\Solution_TestUnit\TestResults\Deploy_user 2021-10-11 20_52_28'
```

Any Idea?